# Visual Studio 2017 Навигация по коду - переход к типу переменной

Tags: visual-studio

Есть клавиша F12, которая делает переход к определению переменной или типа. Очень часто возникает ситуация, что сначала для переменной по F12 делаю переход к месту её определения, чтобы ещё раз нажать F12 по её типу и перейти к определению её типа (класса). Можно ли с помощью одного нажатия какой-то клавиши перейти к определению типа переменной?

Comment: хороший вопрос... чтобы по одной клавише сразу же переходить к определению типа переменной.